# Read the stacked dataset efficiently in R

Tags: r

I have data as follows:

```
 21     i=54,j=33, Y Component
250.04167175293  .486999988555908
250.08332824707  .541999995708466
250.125  .149000003933907
250.16667175293  .49099999666214
250.20832824707  .33899998664856
250.25   .31700000166893
250.29167175293  .36599999666214
250.33332824707  .204999998211861
250.375  .151999995112419
250.41667175293  9.70000028610229E-02
250.45832824707 -.115000002086163
250.5   -.170000001788139
250.54167175293 -.207000002264977
250.58332824707 -.230000004172325
250.625 -.231000006198883
250.66667175293 -.24099999666214
250.70832824707 -.229000002145767
250.75  -.190999999642372
250.79167175293 -.158999994397163
250.83332824707 -.101999998092651
250.875  0
 21     i=55,j=33, Y Component
250.04167175293  .439999997615814
250.08332824707  .507000029087067
250.125  .148000001907349
250.16667175293  .453999996185303
250.20832824707  .316000014543533
250.25   .291999995708466
250.29167175293  .337999999523163
250.33332824707  .19200000166893
250.375  .141000002622604
250.41667175293  8.79999995231628E-02
250.45832824707 -.120999999344349
250.5   -.189999997615814
250.54167175293 -.23199999332428
250.58332824707 -.266999989748001
250.625 -.26800000667572
250.66667175293 -.275000005960464
250.70832824707 -.261999994516373
250.75  -.221000000834465
250.79167175293 -.175999999046326
250.83332824707 -.115000002086163
250.875 -1.20000001043081E-02
 21     i=56,j=33, Y Component
250.04167175293  .439999997615814
250.08332824707  .507000029087067
250.125  .148000001907349
250.16667175293  .453999996185303
250.20832824707  .316000014543533
250.25   .291999995708466
250.29167175293  .337999999523163
250.33332824707  .19200000166893
250.375  .141000002622604
250.41667175293  8.79999995231628E-02
250.45832824707 -.120999999344349
250.5   -.189999997615814
250.54167175293 -.23199999332428
250.58332824707 -.266999989748001
250.625 -.26800000667572
250.66667175293 -.275000005960464
250.70832824707 -.261999994516373
250.75  -.221000000834465
250.79167175293 -.175999999046326
250.83332824707 -.115000002086163
250.875 -1.20000001043081E-02
 21     i=57,j=33, Y Component
250.04167175293  .340999990701675
250.08332824707  .266999989748001
250.125  4.89999987185001E-02
250.16667175293  .273999989032745
250.20832824707  .172999992966652
250.25   .180999994277954
250.29167175293  .206000000238419
250.33332824707  .104000002145767
250.375  8.20000022649765E-02
250.41667175293  5.09999990463257E-02
250.45832824707 -8.50000008940697E-02
250.5   -.100000001490116
250.54167175293 -.123999997973442
250.58332824707 -.14300000667572
250.625 -.140000000596046
250.66667175293 -.144999995827675
250.70832824707 -.137999996542931
250.75  -.112000003457069
250.79167175293 -9.00000035762787E-02
250.83332824707 -5.60000017285347E-02
250.875  1.49999996647239E-02
```

In the above data set, the first row gives info about the following data: i.e 21 is the number of data points and "i=54, j=33, Y Component" is the column name. Then after 21 rows of data the format continues.

I need to convert the data as follows:

```
      time i=54,j=33, Y Component i=55,j=33, Y Component i=56,j=33, Y Component i=57,j=33, Y Component
1 250.0417                  0.487                  0.440                  0.419                  0.341
2 250.0833                  0.542                  0.507                  0.476                  0.267
3 250.1250                  0.149                  0.148                  0.139                  0.049
4 250.1667                  0.491                  0.454                  0.431                  0.274
5 250.2083                  0.339                  0.316                  0.296                  0.173
6 250.2500                  0.317                  0.292                  0.270                  0.181
```

I tried using grep to find the pattern and then merging them but it seems it takes rather long to do for the larger dataset. I am looking for a faster way to read such format and arrange the data.

Comment: I can think of a very efficient way to do this with SAS data step. How commited are you to R? And how big is the larger data set? Hundreds, thousands, millions of records??

Comment: Dataset is in 50000 range. I am committed to R and would appreciate solution in R. I had used SAS in college days and haven't looked at it since then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I defined a couple of functions using `scan` to handle this. I suspect this is not going to be extremely fast, but it is responsive to the data format you have. Let me know how it goes with your full size data set. Note the post-processing to flatten the result out.

The first function defined `readPairs` reads a single chunk of the file with the time and measurement. It reads this from the file using `scan`, taking `2 * nPairs` values. Note that with no delimiter specified on scan, it separates values by whitespace. Data goes into a data frame.

The main function defines the data frame to return. It then opens the connection to the file. This is necessary so we can read the file a bit at a time. Each time the connection is used by a new `scan` call the position in the file is retained by the connection object. When the end of the file is reached a zero length vector is return. This is why the while argument is looking for length greater than zero.

In the loop, the function reads the number of pairs from the file, then the 3 whitespace separated tags. It passes these in to `readPairs` so that it reads the right number and attaches the tag value to the data frame.

```
readPairs <- function(connection, nPairs, tag){
    pairVector <- scan(connection, what=numeric(), n = 2 * nPairs)
    data.frame(
        tag = rep(tag, nPairs),
        time = pairVector[2 * seq_len(nPairs) - 1],
        value = pairVector[2 * seq_len(nPairs)])
}

main <- function(textFile){
    pairData <- data.frame(
        tag = character(),
        time = numeric(),
        value = numeric())
    connection <- file(textFile, "r")
    #get the number of entries to read
    pairs <- scan(connection, what=integer(), n = 1)
    while(length(pairs) > 0){
        #get the descriptive info [three whitespace delim strings]
        desc <- paste(scan(connection, what=character(), n = 3), collapse = " ")
        pairData <- rbind(pairData,
                          readPairs(connection, pairs, desc))
        pairs <- scan(connection, what=integer(), n = 1)
    }
    close(connection)
    pairData
}

pd <- main("filename.txt")

library(tidyr)
spread(pd,tag,value)
```

Comment: Hi vpipkt, thank you so much for this solution. This solution is significantly faster than the solution I have so far. Accepting this as an answer.